# Is copying a book title considered plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, titles

I'd like to know if choosing an already existing book title is a type of plagiarism?

Comment: Take a look at [Should I care if my short story has the same title as someone else's book?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/3929/34330) and the other posts I linked underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this has some answers: [https://www.quora.com/Will-it-be-considered-plagiarism-if-I-title-a-book-The-Love-Club-What-should-I-do-if-it-is#:~:text=No%2C%20because%20according%20to%20the,cannot%20be%20protected%20by%20copyright](https://www.quora.com/Will-it-be-considered-plagiarism-if-I-title-a-book-The-Love-Club-What-should-I-do-if-it-is#:%7E:text=No%2C%20because%20according%20to%20the,cannot%20be%20protected%20by%20copyright).

This links explains what is and isn't protected under copyright laws:

> No, because according to the US Copyright Office, “Copyright law does not protect names, titles, or short phrases or expressions. Even if a name, title, or short phrase is novel or distinctive or lends itself to a play on words, it cannot be protected by copyright.

> "There are several instances of books sharing titles, as well as
> songs, albums, movies, and any number of other things you can
> conceivably imagine. This is because much like names, slogans and
> ideas, titles are not protected by U.S. copyright laws (which is why
> so many books have the same titles). To qualify for copyright
> protection, a work needs to possess “a significant amount of original
> expression”—and while “a significant amount of original expression”
> isn’t fully defined by hard-and-fast rules, the courts have ruled that
> expressions as short as book titles do not qualify."

- Jason Taft, a commenter on the same topic through the provided link.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer? You need to include the relevant text from the link in your answer, so that it can be useful even if your link died. See [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)